# I pasted an address from ETC when i sent ETH to my ledger nano s

Tags: wallets, ethereum-classic, hardware-wallets, ledger-nano-s

I can see the transaction on etherscan.  Is there any way to recover these ether?

Thanks for any help!  If we can recover these I will send one or two for the assistance...

Comment: Where did you get this ETC address from?

Comment: It was generated by the ledger nano s. I mistaking ly opened the etc wallet for receiving instead of the eth wallet. Sent ether from coinbase to the etc address. Thanks for the reply

Comment: The address was generated in ledger ethereum app under etc, I should clarify.

Comment: I can see the view the wallet on my ether wallet with the address, but when I open the ledger nano s it does not show any balance or recognize the wallet with the ether sitting there. I'd love to send 1 eth to someone if we can get me back on track.

Answer (score 2):

Your address/private key pair will work regardless of which network you are connected to. You can just use your account on ETH as if you were on ETC. This is of course assuming the Ethers and the transaction is on ETH.